# Conditional formatting one cell based on contents of an entire row

Tags: excel

Ok, I have read almost every question on here that I could find trying to figure this out...but still can't get it. Here is what I am trying to do:

I want any cell in Column A to be highlighted if there are no values in cells in Columns B through F, in their corresponding rows.

I don't know if I am asking this right...newbie first question here. I just can't figure out how to highlight a cell if any of the cells after it are blank. Also, how to copy this down, or apply it to the entire column A for their corresponding rows.

Thanks

UPDATE: I apologize for my lack of clarification. I took a screenshot of what I am looking for. It is a chain sheet for ownership. Column K is the column that I want to format,depending on the whether values have been entered into any of the cells next to it. (There are some notes that don't transfer ownership, so I want the "0.00000000" to be highlighted if nothing has been entered).
I didn't know if an ISBLANK formula would work, and can't figure it out.
Thanks, and I will edit again if needed. 
[Ownership Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTRBa.png)

Comment: forget about conditional formatting for a moment as that is the easy part.  Instead write a formula that will put in X in the corresponding row of an unsed column.  When you figure that part out, adjust the formula for use in conditional formatting.  You can then also show us the formula you came up with as something you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

To work out if there are values in columns B to F, you could use CountA().

If you create a conditional format with a formula that uses `=counta($B1:$F1)=0` then that format can be applied to any cell you specify in the Conditional Formatting Manager

[image]